# Error starting SQL Server 2017 service. Error Code 3417

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, character-set, encoding

I have SQL Server 2017 installed on my computer. This is what `SELECT @@VERSION` returns:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4293803) - 14.0.2002.14 (X64)   Jul 21 2018 07:47:45   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0  (Build 17134: )`

It was working fine until yesterday. Suddenly `SQL SERVER Service` did not run. When I wanted to run the service manually it showed `3417 error`. When I checked event log I saw this error:

> Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step 'msdb110_upgrade.sql' encountered error 200, state 7, severity 25. This is a serious error condition which might interfere with regular operation and the database will be taken offline. If the error happened during upgrade of the 'master' database, it will prevent the entire SQL Server instance from starting. Examine the previous errorlog entries for errors, take the appropriate corrective actions and re-start the database so that the script upgrade steps run to completion.`

After some googling I found out I can run it with `/T902 switch` and try to fix the problem. But no solution worked for me. So I installed another instance of the same `SQL SERVER 2017` and restored databases. Now the new installed instance has the same problem.

What could be the problem?

**UPDATE**
Here is the full error log of SQL Server.

> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.29 spid6s      Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
>
> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.29 spid6s      Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
>
> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.29 spid6s      Configuration option 'Agent XPs' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
>
> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.29 spid6s      Configuration option 'Agent XPs' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
>
> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.29 spid6s      Creating SSIS folders...
>
> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.30 spid6s      Dropping procedure [dbo].[sp_syscollector_get_instmdw]
>
> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.30 spid6s      Creating procedure [dbo].[sp_syscollector_get_instmdw]...
>
> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.30 spid6s      Dropping procedure [dbo].[sp_syscollector_upload_instmdw]
>
> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.30 spid6s      Creating procedure [dbo].[sp_syscollector_upload_instmdw]...
>
> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.30 spid6s      Uploading data collector package from disk: c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL2017\MSSQL\Install\SqlTraceCollect.dtsx
>
> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.30 spid6s      Uploading data collector package from disk: c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL2017\MSSQL\Install\SqlTraceCollect.dtsx
>
> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.30 spid6s      Error: 2775, Severity: 17, State: 12.
>
> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.30 spid6s      The code page 65001 is not supported by the server.
>
> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.30 spid6s      Error: 912, Severity: 21, State: 2.
>
> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.30 spid6s      Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step 'msdb110_upgrade.sql' encountered error 200, state 7, severity 25. This is a serious error condition which might interfere with regular operation and the database will be taken offline. If the error happened during upgrade of the 'master' database, it will prevent the entire SQL Server instance from starting. Examine the previous errorlog entries for errors, take the appropriate corrective actions and re-start the database so that the script upgrade steps run to completion.
>
> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.30 spid6s      Error: 3417, Severity: 21, State: 3.
>
> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.30 spid6s      Cannot recover the master database. SQL Server is unable to run. Restore master from a full backup, repair it, or rebuild it. For more information about how to rebuild the master database, see SQL Server Books Online.
>
> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.30 spid6s      SQL Server shutdown has been initiated
>
> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.30 spid6s      SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.

**UPDATE**
This line has something to tell. `The code page 65001 is not supported by the server.` My recently windows updated to `Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.285)`. After this update some applications texts has changed to unknown characters. Can this be the cause of the problem?

[image: Registry image for code page]

Comment: tl;dr -- "Code page 65001" is the code page for UTF8. -- Check your system region settings (buried deep in the answer below, skip all the opinions and update junk it doesn't help), and verify that the "UTF-8" beta checkbox is unchecked (again, buried in the answer below).  This fixed it for me and a couple of others.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would start by saying that you are running SQL Server 2017 on Windows 10 (client OS) which is not supported see [Hardware and Software requirements for SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). You are wasting the capability of enterprise edition and lot of money by running it on client OS.

Plus I believe such issues are *mostly* bugs so I would suggest you to apply latest [SQL Server 2017 CU 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4342123). Let me know if that fixes you issue. If you want to try out workaround for this issues please refer to [This Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2010/04/14/unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-immediately-after-applying-service-pack-cumulative-updates/).

As confirmed by OP the issues did not solved even after applying SQL Server 2017 CU10.

EDIT: The problem starts with below statement

> 2018-09-17 13:06:47.30 spid6s The code page 65001 is not supported by the server.

The `code page` 65001 means UTF 8 encoding which is not supported by SQL Server and this I believe is causing the issue. **This is definitely a BUG** I am perplexed why this is still not fixed in CU10. The upgrade process is trying to `bulk load` data having UTF 8 encoding and since SQL Server does not supports it, it is failing.

You have windows 10 go to `control pane`, now select `region and language` applet, it might be just `region` for you on Windows 10. Go to `administrative tab` and in the lower part of tab you have to click on `change system Locale` and then go ahead and activate/select the **Beta: UTF8 Support** and start the windows machine. Below is what options look from my windows 7 machine. The option might be *almost* same for Windows 10.

[image]

As conformed by OP the whole issues started after applying certain OS patch. **The issue was resolved after unchecking the "Beta:UTF8 support"**.  The issue seems to be 2 things.

1. OP already has Beta:UTF8 Support checked and was running fine until he applied OS patch which changed "something".
2. The issue resolved after unchecking Beta:UTF8 Support from control panel with OS patch already there.

The SQL Server was running fine with Beta:UTF8 Support but when OS patch was applied "something" broke in such a way that SQL Server master database was not able to come online which message that code page 65001 is not supported. Disabling Beta:UTF8 from control panel resolved the issue. Although I believe this is more of a workaround and MS need to come out with proper KB article for this.

PS: I also found [Connect Bug](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35245150-bulk-insert-does-not-work-utf-8-support-enabled-fo) already raised for this issue. When I say not supported(for installing Enterprise edition on client OS) that does not means you cannot run this infrastructure it only means you are on your own if you hit some "bug" or something fails unexpectedly. If you raise case with MS about any such issue I am sure they would point this out.

Comment: @Beginner and Shanky: I checked that file (`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Install\SqlTraceCollect.dtsx`) in Notepad++ and it shows an encoding of "UCS-2 LE BOM", which is really UTF-16 LE, which in Microsoft-land is called "Unicode". Not sure if the bug is in Windows or SQL Server, but given that the file has a Byte Order Mark (BOM), it shouldn't have attempted to read it as UTF-8 regardless of the system's default encoding. That is, after all, the entire purpose of having the BOM ;-) The file even starts with: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`.

Comment: I installed the developer edition (SQL Server 2014, have to test backwards compability) and the same thing applies there. Your solution worked great for it.

Comment: The issue was resolved after unchecking the "Beta:UTF8 support". THank @Shanky, i waste two day on this issue and you save my day.

Comment: I had this problem today with the developer edition of SQL Server. -- I've had that beta UTF-8 thing checked for weeks, and SQL Server has been chugging along just fine, until today when it stopped.  Same error message.  Unchecking the box fixed it.  Super weird.

Comment: I just had to create an account and say thank you for the help! This solved my problem with "The code page 65001 is not supported by the server which I put many hours in vain to solve when I tried to install Microsoft Business Central CU 24